# My FFMPEG converter is not allowing mp4 to webm conversions.

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, webm

heres the command:

```
ffmpeg -i videos/test.mp4 -c:v libvpx -level 216 -profile 0 -qmax 42 -qmin 10 -c:a libvorbis -f webm out.webm
```

i keep getting this error:

```
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

here is the full response

```
# ffmpeg -i videos/test.mp4 -c:v libvpx -level 216 -profile 0 -qmax 42 -qmin 10 -c:a 

libvorbis -f webm out.webm
ffmpeg version N-49225-g7e059c9 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 24 2013 05:14:06 with gcc 4.1.2 (GCC) 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)
  configuration: --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvpx --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      52. 15.101 / 52. 15.101
  libavcodec     54. 90.100 / 54. 90.100
  libavformat    54. 61.104 / 54. 61.104
  libavdevice    54.  3.102 / 54.  3.102
  libavfilter     3. 33.100 /  3. 33.100
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'videos/test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp42avc1
    creation_time   : 2010-08-12 15:42:21
  Duration: 00:00:34.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 358 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 100 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-08-12 15:42:21
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x320, 251 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 2997 tbn, 5994 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-08-12 15:42:21
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
Please use -profile:a or -profile:v, -profile is ambiguous
File 'out.webm' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
v0.9.6
[libvpx @ 0x7e38d20] Failed to initialize encoder: ABI version mismatch
Output #0, webm, to 'out.webm':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp42avc1
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p, 640x320, q=10-42, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-08-12 15:42:21
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: none, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-08-12 15:42:21
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (h264 -> libvpx)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (aac -> libvorbis)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

does anybody have any idea whats going on? I am completely lost. I have tried so many different commands. converting from mp4 to ogg works fine, and i have had mp4 to webm working before, but i reinstalled ffmpeg to get the mp4 to ogg working and now ive lost my mp4 to webm conversions. >.< this whole installation process is such a damn nightmare. does anyone havea  good tutorial for centos installation of ffmpeg that will work for mp4 ogg and webm? I have used the centos tut that came off of the ffmpeg site, but it failed me. If anyone has any ideas that could point me in the right direction i would much appreciate it!

Comment: Questions about using FFmpeg command line are off topic for Stack Overflow. Please ask them on [SU] in the future. (But please don't cross-post this one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real problem isn't the settings you're using. It's your FFmpeg configuration:

```
[libvpx @ 0x7e38d20] Failed to initialize encoder: ABI version mismatch
```

This is the Application Binary Interface. The source you built against is obviously different from the actual library being used while encoding.

It seems you have multiple versions of `libvpx` installed. Remove all of them but the latest, and try recompiling FFmpeg. Or download a static build [from the download page](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html), which include `libvpx` for you already.

Comment: ah i think youre on to something! i do have 2 versions on my server but when i try to uninstall them it keeps giving me an error

# make distclean
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `distclean'.  Stop.
make: *** [distclean] Error 2

make uninstall
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `uninstall'.  Stop.
make: *** [uninstall] Error 2

both of those were run from wihtin both installation dirs and both fed me the same error

Comment: How did you install them in the first place? What did you run, `make uninstall`?

Answer (score 1):

From the version output, you are using a `FFmpeg` compiled from official source tree.

`v0.9.6
[libvpx @ 0x7e38d20] Failed to initialize encoder: ABI version mismatch`

From your output log, it seems `FFmpeg` request `libvpx` version `0.9.6`, the `libvpx` you currently integrated isn't `0.9.6`, so `FFmpeg` complained error.

You can find the version matched `libvpx` from [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/downloads.webmproject.org/releases/webm/index.html), download and recompile it.

Answer (score 0):

Your input file has the audio and video streams backwards.  You will have to remap them for this conversion.

add

```
-map 0:1 -map 0:0
```

in that order to tell ffmpeg that the input is A,V when it defaults output to V,A

Comment: how were you able to determine that? sorry, i am sort of lost in this video-conversion world. So much information to digest, and it seems like if i dont understand it all im just ganna keep hitting these brick walls. In any case, however, what you gave me did not work. Perhaps that was part of the problem, but im receiving the same exact error

Comment: @Isaac You are wrong libvpx is a video codec and libvorbis audio, remapping is not needed!

Comment: @d33pika, You're right... I see the mapping auto switched at the bottom.

Comment: @user2009044, you can see the input stream in the printout where it says "Stream #0:0(eng): Audio" under "Input #0"